# Fail to send an HTTP POST request in C

Tags: c, sockets, desktop-application

i've tried to send a HTTP POST request using Code::Blocks .c, but i don't know what is wrong with the message, i search in the google and all the tutorials teach me to do like i did, so if someone can help me i'll thank you, here is my request to the site::

```
    sprintf(buffer, "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Lenght: %d\r\n", 7+strlen(action)+3+strlen(id));
strcat(buffer, "Host: www.testserv.com \r\n\r\n");
strcat(buffer, "action=");strcat(buffer, action);
strcat(buffer, "&");
strcat(buffer, "id=");strcat(buffer, id);

printf("Requisicao:\n%s\n\n", buffer);

send(s, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
```

the request seems right, but she don't works something wrong?

----EDITED---
The problem is: my post request does not work, only the HTTP header is interpreted by the server, but the values for the form itens does not!

explaining the site:
the site have a index.php page and a second page called  by the index.php: send.php.
The index page have a form with 3 itens: 2 textbox's(action and id) and a submit button, i write anything on the 2 textbox's (for tests) and when i press the submit, the form through the POST method will call the send.php page and this page will show us what i have wrote in the 2 textbox's, the function that i will show you is for connect with the server, and ask for send.php with the method POST and try to pass for the server the values for the textbox's variables.

here is the complete function:

```
int enviar(const char* action, const char* id){

#define ACTION "action="
#define ID "&id="

char head[500], buff_msg[500];
int s, len;
struct sockaddr_in inf;

if((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    return -1;

inf.sin_family = AF_INET;
inf.sin_port = htons(80);
inf.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.1.10.1");
memset(inf.sin_zero, 0, 8);

if(connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&inf, sizeof(inf)) == -1)
    return -1;

memset(head, 0, 500);
memset(buff_msg, 0, 500);

sprintf(head, "POST /page_called_by_the_index.php / HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Length: %d\r\n",
                                                    strlen(ACTION)+strlen(action)
                                                   +strlen(ID)+strlen(id));
strcat(head, "host: the_server.com\r\n\r\n");
strcat(head, ACTION);
strcat(head, action);
strcat(head, ID);
strcat(head, id);

printf("Header HTTP[%d]:\n%s\n", strlen(cab), cab);

len = send(s,head, strlen(cab), 0);

if(len <= 0){
    perror("send");
    return 0;
}

printf("%d bytes have been sent\n", len);

while((len=recv(s, buff_msg, 500, 0)) > 0){
    printf("%d bytes read:\n%s\n", len, buff_msg);
    memset(buff_msg, 0, 500);
}

return 1;}
```

the header request is good because the server sent me back 200 OK, but the values
are not interpreted!

i thank you for the help.

Comment: What are the errors or problems you are seeing?

Comment: Your buffer contains \r\n too.I hope its not the actual name for HTTP request.Make sure socket is connected before send.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of errors in your POST command

```
Content-Lenght
```

should be

```
Content-Length
```

and

```
7+strlen(action)+3+strlen(id)
```

is one character too short assuming the 3 for `&id=` (this requires 4 characters so your content length will omit the last character of your id).  It would be safer if you used variables (or defines) for the strings whose lengths you're currently hard-coding

```
#define ACTION "action="
#define ID "&id="

sprintf(buffer, "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Length: %d\r\n",
                sizeof(ACTION)-1+strlen(action)+sizeof(ID)-1+strlen(id));
strcat(buffer, "Host: www.testserv.com \r\n\r\n");
strcat(buffer, ACTION);
strcat(buffer, action);
strcat(buffer, ID);
strcat(buffer, id);
```

Comment: hmm, your tip improved my function, but the main problem persist, the values aren't sent to the site

Comment: You never said what your problem was before.  Can you update your post to show code that declares/allocates `buffer` and connects your socket?  If you've written your own server, code for that would be good too.